# Xamarin API's with WebAPI Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Xamarin. After Adding Web Api to my Xamarin Proj, I added the Nuget package "Plugin.RestClient" but i could NOT find the Auto Generated namespace "Plugin.RestClient".

Please help

Comment: you have to add it using `using`

Comment: Why do you use `Plugin.RestClient` ? Which tutorial did you follow ? You just need `HttpClient` to consume web service , ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/web-service/?tabs=vswin&tutorial-step=2

Comment: Hi Cole. this is the Tut i was following:  https://youtu.be/Lir75oNAeiM

Comment: The video is too old and the plugin is no longer maintained 4 fours ago , check the latest docs i provided above.